# How to efficiently remove var in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, priority-queue, var

I am trying to solve problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connect-n-ropes-minimum-cost/

Solution

```
def minCost(arr: Array[Int]):Int = {

  val minHeap = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue.empty[Int].reverse
    
  arr.foreach{ ele =>
    minHeap += ele
  }
    
  var sum =0
    
  while(minHeap.size >1){
    
    val first = minHeap.dequeue()
    val second = minHeap.dequeue()
    
    val length = second + first//3+3 =6+9
    sum = sum + (first +second)//3+6+9
    
    minHeap.enqueue(length)
  }
    
  sum
}
```

I want to get rid of `while` loop and `var`. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

tried below

```
val res =minHeap.foldLeft(0){
  (x,y)=>
    val sum =x+y
    minHeap.enqueue(sum)
    sum
}

println(res)
res
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to remove the `var` and `while` but still use a mutable **PriorityQueue** *(which being honest is a good compromise and probably the best to do in real code)* you can just use a tail-recursive method.

```scala
type Ropes = List[Int]

def connectRopes(ropes: Ropes): Int = {
  val queue = PriorityQueue.from(ropes).reverse
  
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
    if (remaining == 0) acc
    else if (remaining == 1) acc
    else {
      val rope1 = queue.dequeue()
      val rope2 = queue.dequeue()
      val newRope = rope1 + rope2
      queue.addOne(newRope)
      loop(remaining - 1, acc + newRope)
    }
  }
  
  loop(remaining = queue.size, acc = 0)
}
```

But, if you want to write a fully immutable solution just to get used to work with immutable data structures you can do something like this:

```scala
def connectRopesFullImmutable(ropes: Ropes): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: Ropes, acc: Int): Int =
    remaining match {
      case Nil =>
        acc
      
      case _ :: Nil =>
        acc
      
      case rope1 :: rope2 :: Nil =>
        rope1 + rope2 + acc
      
      case rope1 :: rope2 :: tail =>
        @annotation.tailrec
        def findTwoMin(remaining: Ropes, min1: Int, min2: Int, acc: Ropes): (Int, Int, Ropes) =
          remaining match {
            case rope :: tail =>
              if (rope < min1) findTwoMin(remaining = tail, min1 = rope, min2 = min1, min2:: acc)
              else if (rope < min2) findTwoMin(remaining = tail, min1, min2 = rope, min2 :: acc)
              else findTwoMin(remaining = tail, min1, min2, rope :: acc)
            
            case Nil =>
              (min1, min2, acc)
          }
      
        val (min1, min2, ropes) =
          if (rope1 < rope2) findTwoMin(remaining = tail, min1 = rope1, min2 = rope2, acc = List.empty)
          else findTwoMin(remaining = tail, min1 = rope2, min2 = rope1, acc = List.empty)
        val newRope = min1 + min2
        loop(remaining = newRope :: ropes, acc + newRope)
    }
  
  loop(remaining = ropes, acc = 0)
}
```

---

Answering the comment the space complexity of the problem is *(AFAIK)* **O(1)**, since the algorithm is a tail-recursive function we are not consuming stack and we only manipulate the same list so we are also not consuming heap.
The time complexity is **O(N^2)** because we have an inner loop inside the outer loop, this means this algorithm is very inefficient.

We may try to optimize it a little by keeping the list of remaining ropes always sorted; as shown below. Which should give use **O(N log(N))**, but still requires a lot of boilerplate and inefficiency just for not using a mutable priority queue.

```scala
def connectRopesFullImmutableOptimized(ropes: Ropes): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: Ropes, acc: Int): Int =
    remaining match {
      case rope1 :: rope2 :: tail =>
        val newRope = rope1 + rope2
      
        @annotation.tailrec
        def insertSorted(remaining: Ropes, acc: Ropes): Ropes =
          remaining match {
            case rope :: ropes =>
              if (newRope > rope) insertSorted(remaining = ropes, rope :: acc)
              else acc reverse_::: (newRope :: rope :: ropes)
            
            case Nil =>
              (newRope :: acc).reverse
          }
      
        loop(remaining = insertSorted(remaining = tail, acc = List.empty), acc + newRope)
      
      case _ =>
        acc
    }
  
  loop(remaining = ropes.sorted, acc = 0)
}
```

---

*You can see the code running in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/efw2lgKJTtG8GvEG1hUAVg/16)*.

Comment: I think you should also include the type alias for `Ropes` in your code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you help to identify the time and space complexity of algo
since we are using tail recursion time complexity will O(1) and time complexity will be O(nlogn) is my understanding correct

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry for confusion ,I was asking about the first about using Priority Queue

Comment: @coder25 ah, yeah that one is **O(1)** in space, not sure about time complexity since I do not know the complexity of the `PriorityQueue` operations.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with `unfold()`. (Scala 2.13.x)

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

def minCost(arr: Array[Int]): Int =
  List.unfold(PriorityQueue(arr:_*).reverse){ pq =>
    Option.when(pq.size > 1) {
      val link = pq.dequeue() + pq.dequeue()
      pq.enqueue(link)
      (link, pq)
    }
  }.sum
```

Comment: May as well use `Iterator.unfold` to avoid the intermediate collection.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty similar @Luis solution, if you are fine with mutability a tail recursion with an accumulator would be sufficient to get rid of `var`s and loops.

```scala
object ConnectRopes extends App {
  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  import scala.collection.mutable

  val arr = List(4, 3, 2, 6)

  val minHeap = mutable.PriorityQueue.from(arr)(Ordering[Int].reverse)

  @tailrec
  def minCost(acc: Int = 0): Int =
    if (minHeap.size > 1) {
      val connect = minHeap.dequeue + minHeap.dequeue
      minHeap.enqueue(connect)
  
      minCost(acc + connect)
    } else acc

  println(minCost())
}
```

However I don't think you can have a immutable solution with comparable time complexity just with lists. For an immutable priority queue you will need a Finger Tree like [this one from ScalaZ](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/FingerTree.scala).